# Is the keyword new and its counterpart delete outdated considering smart pointers and the functions std::make_shared and std::make_unique?

Tags: c++

It seems to me that `new` and its counterpart `delete` are outdated, because there
are smart pointers and the functions `std::make_shared` and `std::make_unique`.
Is that true?

Comment: They are not outdated in the sense that you still need them if you're writing a custom smart pointer or a container. Otherwise yes, they should be avoided.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat For Containers one would mostly work with allocators since `new []` has problems like only being able to use the default constructor. For custom smart pointers one can often also use a std smart pointer internally and have less worries about memory leaks and exception safety. I don't want to say that `new` and `delete` cannot be useful there but I think they can also be avoided very often.

Comment: The library facilities you refer to actually *use* operator `new` and `delete` by default.    And it would be harder for an implementation to provide sensible default behaviour for those facilities if `new` and `delete` were removed from the language, since the equivalent functionality would need to be written somehow - for example, in assembler.     The fact that there are library facilities that make it less error-prone to manage dynamically allocated  memory doesn't mean that the core language features that are *used* by those facilities outdated in any way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ is really a multi-level language. At its highest level, you seldom use explicitely `new` and `delete` because their calls are encapsulated in smart pointers or *containers*

But you might need to build a specialized container class. C++ is still a nice language for that, since the standard library is mainly coded in C++. In that case, you will certainly have to manage explicite allocation and deallocation. That is what I would call mid-level programming.

You can even use C++ on dedicated hardware and embedded systems. In that case, it could even make sense to implement specific allocation function, that would be used through `new` and `delete` in mid-level code to allow the highest level part of a program to use (possibly specific) containers and smart pointers.

TL/DR: `new` and `delete` are generally not required  in high level constructs. Yet they are an essential and not outdated at all part of the language.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not true. Not everyone will use smart pointers. There's a price you have to pay for them, especially for `shared_ptr`. For example consider you are writing a garbage collector. Or some crazy runtime with [tagged pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer). You probably won't use built-in smart pointers at all. So it all depends on what you are doing.

`new/delete` is not outdated. It's a low level feature that requires extra care. It's just that smart pointers' safety often outweights any benefits from `new/delete` and that's why they are recommended by default. But a sword is not useless just because most people don't know how to wield it without cutting themselves.

Comment: @Caleth it might be in some abstract sense, but it is neither shared_ptr nor unique_ptr which the OP refers to.